# Como acessar o object window de outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, aplicação-web

Estou fazendo uma requisição via Ajax, consigo capturar o html, porém queria ter acesso ao object window da página que ele fez a requisição, isso é possível?

Exemplo como estou usando.

```
$('#link').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'www.google.com.br',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {
       var x = JSON.stringify(res.window);
       alert(x);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Não é possível (pelo menos até onde sei).

Answer (score 0):

> consigo capturar o html

Consegue? Essa requisição nem sequer será possível, pois para fazer uma requisição para outro domínio, esse outro domínio precisa aceitar seu endereço no header Access-Control-Allow-Origin, ou então o próprio browser irá bloquear a resposta.
Mas se você usou o google apenas como exemplo, você pode anexar todo o html que você recebeu dentro de um elemento `<iframe>` para isola-lo, e então acessar o window com

```
var meuIframe = document.getElementById('meuIframe');
var objetoWindow = meuIframe.contentWindow;
```

Comment: Acho que o `www.google.com.br` foi apenas um exemplo, visto que a requisição seria feita para `https://www.domain.com/www.google.com.br` devido à falta do `//`